# modulenotfounderror no module named 'modin'

Tags: python, import, modin

I have created a virtual environment with following syntax in the windows terminal:

```
conda create --prefix ./modinenv python=3.6 numpy
conda activate e:\modin\modinenv
pip install modin[dask]
jupyter notebook
```

In a new python file, when i executed this following command:

```
import modin.pandas as pd
```

it gives me an error: **modulenotfounderror no module named 'modin'**

I searched many forum, but got no workable response to this.

I even tried following before import statement:

```
import os
os.environ["MODIN_ENGINE"] = "dask" # Modin will use Dask
import modin.pandas as pd
```

This also does not work here. So any help in this regard is appreciated.

Thanks
Gopinath

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same environment setting as you.

```
import os
import modin.pandas as pd
os.environ["MODIN_ENGINE"] = "dask"
```

Try following:

1. It seems that your Modin may not install properly, so please try `pip install -U modin`  according to [Modin documentation](https://modin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)
2. pip3 install 'modin[dask]'